# How to tell Matlab to "reload" the functions that exist in a folder in my path?

Tags: function, matlab, path

I keep many homemade functions in a common directory like this:
U:\matlab\functions
(U: is a mapped network drive in Windows 10).

In my startup.m I add it to my path:

```
addpath('U:\matlab\functions');
```

I can access functions in that directory with no problems until I add a new function in that directory during a session.  After I add a new function and try to use it, Matlab doesn't find it.  I try to use the new function and it says

```
Unrecognized function or variable 'newfunction'
```

Or I do a

```
which newfunction
```

and it says

```
'newfunction' not found
```

I have to close and restart the Matlab session to have it find the new function I just created.  Is there any way to tell Matlab to "reload" what it sees in the functions directory that is included in my path without restarting my session?

I'm using Matlab R2022a, but I've seen this in earlier versions.

Comment: `U:` is likely a network drive? MATLAB will automatically find new functions in directories on local drives, but I guess automatically refreshing network drives is too expensive so it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [rehash](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rehash.html):

> rehash updates the MATLAB® list of known files and classes for folders on the search path that are not in matlabroot. It compares the timestamps for loaded functions against their timestamps on disk. It clears loaded functions if the files on disk are newer.

Comment: Thank you!  I ran "rehash path" and that worked.  "rehash" by itself didn't work.